# ASP MVC error when accessing http://localhost:59730/Controller/Index

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am experiencing an odd occurrence.

If I navigate to:
`http://localhost:59730/Controller`
I get served the correct page and it is displays everything correctly.

But if I navigate to:
`http://localhost:59730/Controller/Index`  It loads the page but it doesn't seem to load any css or scripts?

Why would this be?  It is essentially navigating to the same page? It must have something to do with asp.net mvc routing I think??

I have just dumped my references in the main layout file: (my plan to go and organise them at a later stage)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Content/Template/js/plugins/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Content/Template/js/plugins/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Content/Template/js/plugins/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Content/Template/js/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Content/Template/js/custom/general.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Content/Template/js/custom/dashboard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Content/Template/js/custom/tables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Content/Template/js/plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show how you reference the CSS in the page? Are you using `@Url.Content` or `Scripts.Render`, or are you just using relative paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference your contents (like js, css, images...) with Url.Content like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Template/js/custom/general.js")"></script>;
```